# Expression SFINAE without enable_if?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have written a program as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
auto serialize(const T& t) -> decltype(to_string(t))
{
    return to_string(t);
}

template <typename T>
auto serialize(const T& t) -> string
{
    return "<object>";
}


int main()
{
    cout<<serialize(4)<<endl;
    cout<<serialize(vector<int>())<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When the program type is supported by `to_string`, I would like the first template being used. But if there is not support for the type by `to_string`, then I would like the second template being used.

I like to see the following results

```
4
<object>
```

But when I compile the program, I get the following error

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:22:19: error: call of overloaded ‘serialize(int)’ is ambiguous
  cout<<serialize(4)<<endl;
                   ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

And I actually cannot blame the compiler. How can I remove this ambiguity without using `enable_if` or `enable_if_t`. Keeping the program simple by SFINAE with expression. In fact, `decltype(to_string(t))` is clear. But, types do not have `not` or `otherwise` operators.

Comment: any reason for downvote?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use `std::enable_if`?

Comment: Any reason not to use `std::enable_if`? It's made for the sole purpose of simplifying SFINAE usage.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, because I want to know if expression SFINAE without `enable_if` can survive?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, there is no reason to use `enable_if` provided that programming without it can be simpler.

Comment: @David88 SFINAE doesn't depend on `std::enable_if`. To the contrary, `std::enable_if` was design to allow SFINAE without the extremely ugly syntax sometimes associated with it. It seems like you may be more interested in find a non-SFINAE solution than finding a SFINAE solution without `std::enable_if`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, then is there any neat solution for this question?

Comment: @David88 Is the goal to use the first overload if `std::to_string` supports that argument and to use the second overload otherwise?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, Yes exactly.

Comment: You're missing the "choose between them when both are valid" part. This requires either disabling the second overload through SFINAE, or adding a parameter which requires a low-rank conversion to lower the overload's priority.

Comment: @Quentin, "disabling the second overload" will be amazing. But how to do that without `enable_if`?

Comment: @David88 I suppose "write your own `std::enable_if`" is not the answer you're looking for? ;)

Comment: @David88 That's about equally difficult with or without `std::enable_if`. The difficult part is writing a type trait that checks if a type is supported by `std::to_string` or not. Once you have that, you can disable the second overload relatively easily with or without `std::enable_if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might prioritize your overloads with extra argument:

```
template <std::size_t N> struct OverloadPriority : OverloadPriority<N -1> {};
template <> struct OverloadPriority<0> {};

template <typename T>
auto serialize_impl(const T& t, OverloadPriority<1>) -> decltype(to_string(t))
{
    return to_string(t);
}

template <typename T>
auto serialize_impl(const T& t, OverloadPriority<0>) -> std::string
{
    return "<object>";
}

template <typename T>
decltype(auto) serialize(const T& t)
{
    return serialize_impl(t, OverloadPriority<1>{});
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2070ee64b3b32d2)

Comment: Very cool solution. But I feel it's missing an explanation of how `OverloadPriority` gives priority to overloads.

Comment: I think it is based on template specialization thatn SFINAE. Am I right?

Comment: @David88 There's no SFINAE involved. It has to do with `OverloadPriority<1>` being a closer match to `OverloadPriority<1>` than `OverloadPriority<0>`. Your comment goes to show how much this answer needs an explanation.

Comment: It is because `OverloadPriority<N>` is deriving from OverloadPriority<N -1>, so when you give an `OverloadPriority<N>` to a function, it will try to fetch the best one

Comment: @David88: the only specialization is to define `OverloadPriority`. Else there are overload, with one which use SFINAE.

Comment: I fail to see why this is simpler than `std::enable_if`. If was responsible for mantaining this code in the future, my first thought would be: "why, just why?". Granted, the OP specifically asked for this, so I think it's a good answer, nonetheless.

Comment: @CássioRenan: For `std::enable_if`, you need to create a traits `have_to_string` (possible with [std::experimental::is_detected](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) for example), if you have more than 2 overloads, you have to check that each ones are mutually exclusive (`to_string(t)` vs `t.to_string()` vs .. vs other). giving order seems simpler in that case.

Comment: @CássioRenan, Because the academic mafia tries to teach you `enable_if` before `SFINAE`. That's so bad for the students.

Comment: "Academic mafia"? Really? Teaching `enable_if` before SFINAE doesn't sound bad at all: The best teachers tend to show how to use something, **then** explain "here, this is how it works". If it was any different, we would have to teach calculus to kids before teaching them newtonian physics.

Comment: @Jarod42 sure, but this trait can be easily implemented using `void_t`. Any good C++ developer would then know exactly what is goin on just by looking at it. Don't get me wrong: Your code is simple and easy enough to understand, but it does require some analysis so I can know what is going on. A simple type trait has the advantage of being a common idiom that doesn't require deeper analysis.

Comment: @CássioRenan: I don't only talk about creating traits, but handling classes which can use several/all ways will lead to "complicated" conditions (all combinations (but grows fast :( `pow(2, N)` (`a&b;a&!b;!a&b;!a&!b`) ) for simpler changes to select between `to_string(t)` vs `t.to_string()`; or minimal combination (`a;!a&b;!a&!b`) but harder to make previous changes). And imagine then if you have to add another method/function `std::string stringify(const T&);`, you have to touch all existing functions `enable_if` conditions. Mine only add one overload, and possibly priorities.

Comment: BTW, priority is not incompatible with `enable_if` and type traits.